# Is there a way to suppress some SonarCloud warnings in TS source code?

Tags: typescript, sonarcloud

I just have some code that keeps giving me a warning in SonarCloud but it was pre-generated with the  framework I am using. Is there a way similar to how `// @ts-ignore` works but for SonarCloud.

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/63377294/3708208 is of help - it just displays the java way :)

Comment: I have seen it, but as you know TS doesn't support specific error suppression and when using ts-ignore SonarCloud still checks it. # pragma also not supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here [How do I ignore duplicated code report in Sonar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52865737/how-do-i-ignore-duplicated-code-report-in-sonar#52869313) . Well, now i know the drop down is there for a reason